# What is this red line through the Xcode import auto suggest

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

What is this red line and what does it mean? This is Xcode 7.3, Cocoapods 0.39.0

[image: Red line in question]

After typing out the import I don't see any errors or warnings. I can use the library with no problems. The library itself has warnings but those are related to Xcode 7.3 changes to swift. I have never noticed this before.

Sometimes Xcode says my Pod project does not have recommended settings, but this still happens after applying the recommended settings.

Comment: Thanks, I kept searching red line and couldn't find anything - strikethrough was the keyword I was missing!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it might just be a bug with Xcode. Ever since the update, I have noticed there are red strike-thoughs on some of the frameworks.

[image: UIKit strike-thru]

As long as it works when you compile, everything should be fine.

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted I believe this is true

Comment: @pbush25 because this question is a duplicate (see the dupe target), and this answer just reiterates the answers in the linked dupe target.

Comment: @BrianOgden I didn't downvote, but I can understand why someone would.  This answer just restates the same info that is in the linked duplicate.